# how to force bash to deliver a signal to another process?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have two processes. I am spawning the first process from the console(bash). And the first process is intern spawning the second process. The second process is reading from a file till it gets a SIGINT or SIGTERM signal from the user. But when I am pressing ctrl+c, bash program is delivering 
the signal to the first process, so it's getting killed and my application goes down, because I did not handle it there.

so my question is how can I force bash program to deliver the signal to the second process ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bash do not generate signal, the tty generate signals to active process. Set the child process active (by using `tcsetpgrp`) so it will receive signals from tty.

before do it, please read articles about how tty works.

Comment: can you provide me a link where tty explained very well or which is your favourite ??

Comment: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php  I think this is good tutorial.